# Debugger shows incorrect result with string.IsNullOrEmpty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm checking each datarow in a datatable to see if there are any empty o null values. For one particular item, I changed (in the debugger) the value to an empty string. So my watch windows looks like the following.

The issue is that `string.IsNullOrEmpty` returns false even though `row["Oracle"]` is an empty string. I set `row["Oracle"]` to `""` and `string.Empty`. Either way, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` returns false.

How come?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code..

Comment: You need to refresh the evaluation of the expression by clicking on the button in the Value-column

Comment: Did you re-evaluate the `IsNullOrEmpty` expression after you changed the value in debugger?

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice the values were gray and not black. Thanks.

Comment: Do I delete this question? What's the protocol for questions where the answer's in a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarcoLaser suggested that I click the Refresh button in the "Value" column to refresh the evaluation of the expression. That seemed to work.